# arreglo de objetos javascript

Tags: javascript

No sé como tendría que usar un bucle `for ... in`, pero llegué al punto que no sé cómo hacer para implementar los parámetros en las sentencias.

**EJERCICIO:**

Utils:

```javascript
var paises = [
   {
       nombre: "argentina",
   continente: "sudamerica",
   poblacion: 40000000
   },
   {
       nombre: "brasil",
   continente: "sudamerica",
   poblacion: 300000000
   },
   {
       nombre: "venezuela",
   continente: "sudamerica",
   poblacion: 25000000
   },
   {
       nombre: "chile",
   continente: "sudamerica",
   poblacion: 10000000
   },
   {
       nombre: "australia",
   continente: "oceania",
   poblacion: 18000000
   },
   {
       nombre: "nueva zelanda",
   continente: "oceania",
   poblacion: 8000000
   },
   {
       nombre: "china",
   continente: "asia",
   poblacion: 1000000000
   },
   {
       nombre: "tailandia",
   continente: "asia",
   poblacion: 32000000
   },
   {
       nombre: "vietnam",
   continente: "asia",
   poblacion: 23000000
   },
   {
       nombre:"‘españa",
   continente: "europa",
   poblacion: 29000000
   },
   {
       nombre: "alemania",
   continente: "europa",
   poblacion: 33000000
   },
   {
       nombre: "francia",
   continente: "europa",
   poblacion: 65000000
   },
   {
       nombre: "portugal",
   continente: "europa",
   poblacion: 4000000
   },
   {
       nombre: "grecia",
   continente: "europa",
   poblacion: 12000000
   },
]
```

Deben crear una función llamada `doubleFilter` que reciba como parámetro un arreglo de objetos, un continente, y un número de población.

La función filtra el arreglo solo con los países que sean del continente pasado por parámetro, y además, los que su población sea mayor o igual a la del ultimo parámetro.

Deberá devolver una matriz con los nombres de los países de los objetos que cumplan con la condición.

```
    function doubleFilter (arr,cont,num){
        let newArr=[]
        for(let i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i]==cont && arr[i]>=num){
                newArr.push(arr[i])
            }
        }
      return newArr
                
    }
```

Llegué a esto, que por lo menos me devuelve una matriz, pero vacía.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casi aciertas con la solución, pero se te ha olvidado comprobar las propiedades de cada elemento (`continente` y `poblacion`):

```
/* En vez de usar: */
if (arr[i] == cont && arr[i] >= num) {
/* Debes usar: */
if (arr[i].continente == cont && arr[i].poblacion >= num) {
```

La solución puede variar, pero si te pide usar un bucle `for ... in`, entonces esta solución podría ser la que necesitas:

```js
let datos = [{nombre:"argentina",continente:"sudamerica",poblacion:40000000},{nombre:"brasil",continente:"sudamerica",poblacion:300000000},{nombre:"venezuela",continente:"sudamerica",poblacion:25000000},{nombre:"chile",continente:"sudamerica",poblacion:10000000},{nombre:"australia",continente:"oceania",poblacion:18000000},{nombre:"nueva zelanda",continente:"oceania",poblacion:8000000},{nombre:"china",continente:"asia",poblacion:1000000000},{nombre:"tailandia",continente:"asia",poblacion:32000000},{nombre:"vietnam",continente:"asia",poblacion:23000000},{nombre:"‘españa",continente:"europa",poblacion:29000000},{nombre:"alemania",continente:"europa",poblacion:33000000},{nombre:"francia",continente:"europa",poblacion:65000000},{nombre:"portugal",continente:"europa",poblacion:4000000},{nombre:"grecia",continente:"europa",poblacion:12000000}];

function doubleFilter (arr, cont, num) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (const i in arr) {
    if (arr[i].continente == cont && arr[i].poblacion >= num) {
      newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(doubleFilter(datos, "europa", 33000000));
```

---

Si no es obligatorio el uso del bucle `for ... in`, entonces podrías crear una función de este tipo que use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
let datos = [{nombre:"argentina",continente:"sudamerica",poblacion:40000000},{nombre:"brasil",continente:"sudamerica",poblacion:300000000},{nombre:"venezuela",continente:"sudamerica",poblacion:25000000},{nombre:"chile",continente:"sudamerica",poblacion:10000000},{nombre:"australia",continente:"oceania",poblacion:18000000},{nombre:"nueva zelanda",continente:"oceania",poblacion:8000000},{nombre:"china",continente:"asia",poblacion:1000000000},{nombre:"tailandia",continente:"asia",poblacion:32000000},{nombre:"vietnam",continente:"asia",poblacion:23000000},{nombre:"‘españa",continente:"europa",poblacion:29000000},{nombre:"alemania",continente:"europa",poblacion:33000000},{nombre:"francia",continente:"europa",poblacion:65000000},{nombre:"portugal",continente:"europa",poblacion:4000000},{nombre:"grecia",continente:"europa",poblacion:12000000}];

const doubleFilter = (paises, continente, poblacionMin) => paises.filter(pais =>
  pais.continente == continente
  && pais.poblacion >= poblacionMin
);

console.log(doubleFilter(datos, "europa", 33000000));
```

El parámetro de `Array.filter()` es una función que determinará con su valor de retorno si el elemento se elimina (`false`) o mantiene (`true`).

Recuerda que las siguientes construcciones:

```
argumento/s => retorno
función = argumento(s) => retorno
función = argumento(s) => { código }
```

Son equivalentes a:

```
function (argumento/s) { return retorno; }
function función(argumento/s) { return retorno; }
function función(argumento/s) { código }
```

El uso de las [*funciones flecha*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) puede reducir la cantidad de código necesario para implementar una función y mejorar su lectura.

Comment: Gracias Oscar por la explicación, claro me faltaba la dot notacion y tambien habia intentado en bucle for in , y como veo tmb me faltaban algunos datos pero estaba por el camino correcto!! muy agradecido con tu respuesta.

Comment: Un placer, sobre todo ayudarte a entender por qué no funcionaba tu solución tal y como la habías pensado. En tu pregunta haces referencia a usar un bucle `for ... in`, pero si no es necesario hacer uso de ese tipo de bucle entonces habría otras soluciones posibles. Edito la respuesta para agregarte otra más.

Answer (score 2):

Con [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) lo puedes hacer, filter crea un nuevo array con las condiciones que se indican dentro de filter(), en este caso dentro de filter implementas con la [función flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) las condiciones que quieres que cumpla el nuevo array, en este caso que sea igual que el continente pasado y que sea mayor la población.

```js
var paises = [
{nombre: "argentina", continente: "sudamerica", poblacion: 40000000},
{nombre: "brasil", continente: "sudamerica", poblacion: 300000000},
{nombre: "venezuela", continente: "sudamerica", poblacion: 25000000},
{nombre: "chile", continente: "sudamerica", poblacion: 10000000},
{nombre: "australia", continente: "oceania", poblacion: 18000000},
{nombre: "nueva zelanda", continente: "oceania", poblacion: 8000000},
{nombre: "china", continente: "asia", poblacion: 1000000000},
{nombre: "tailandia", continente: "asia", poblacion: 32000000},
{nombre: "vietnam", continente: "asia", poblacion: 23000000},
{nombre:"‘españa", continente: "europa", poblacion: 29000000},
{nombre: "alemania", continente: "europa", poblacion: 33000000},
{nombre: "francia", continente: "europa", poblacion: 65000000},
{nombre: "portugal", continente: "europa", poblacion: 4000000},
{nombre: "grecia", continente: "europa", poblacion: 12000000},
];

function filtrar(paises, continente, poblacion){
    return paises.filter(pais => pais.continente == continente && pais.poblacion >= poblacion);
}

var f = filtrar(paises, "oceania", 3000);
console.log(f);
```

Comment: Es la respuesta que se busca cuando uno está con estos problemas, pero estaría bien que explicaras en cada parte del código qué es lo que se hace y qué espera devolver, porque aunque tú y yo lo sepamos, los próximos que vengan y lean esto lo entenderán en el momento, pero con el tiempo puede que necesiten volver a buscarlo porque no les quedó claro del todo.

Comment: Gracias Vicent!

Comment: Cierto Sergio, lo intento.